# Testing for a root larger than 1 in AR(p)

Tags: time-series, unit-root

My question is the following: 
How to test for a root larger than 1 in AR(p) process from its observations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In unit root larger than 1, do you mean higher integration order than one ($I(1)$ which is a unit root)? If you suspect a process is integrated of order two, $I(2)$, you can run the unit root test on the differenced series. If the differenced series also have a unit root, the integration order is higher than one.

Comment: NO. I am asking for a test than can tell if there is a root(s) greater than 1 in the AR(p) process. I am not asking for integration order.